# How to get data from multiple tables using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my tables.

```
class maindevotee(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(225))
    phonenumber = db.Column(db.String(225))
    gothram = db.Column(db.String(225))
    date = db.Column(db.String(50))
    address = db.Column(db.String(250))

    def json(self):
        return {'id': self.id, 'name':self.name, 'phonenumber': self.phonenumber, 'gothram': self.gothram,
                'date': self.date, 'address': self.address}

class relatives(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    main_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('maindevotee.id'), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(225))
    star = db.Column(db.String(225))
    gender = db.Column(db.String(45))
    relation = db.Column(db.String(45))

    def json(self):
        return {'main_id': self.main_id, 'name': self.name, 'star':self.star,
                'gender': self.gender, 'relation': self.relation}
    
class services(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    main_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('maindevotee.id'), nullable=False)
    pooja = db.Column(db.String(225))
    god = db.Column(db.String(225))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    donation = db.Column(db.String(225))
    booking_fromdate = db.Column(db.String(50))
    booking_todate = db.Column(db.String(50))
    prasadam = db.Column(db.String(225))

    def json(self):
        return {'main_id': self.main_id, 'pooja': self.pooja, 'god': self.god,
                'price': self.price, 'donation': self.donation, 'booking_fromdate': self.booking_fromdate,
                'booking_todate': self.booking_todate, 'prasadam': self.prasadam}
```

How to get data from multiple tables in a single request. Here is my scource code to join the three tables.
If i am try to get data from database it will raise an error.
and the error is   AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'get_data'
can i get the data from database using foreign key.

```
data = db.session.query(maindevotee, relatives, services)\
    .filter(maindevotee.phonenumber == 3251469870)\
    .join(relatives, maindevotee.id == relatives.main_id)\
    .join(services, maindevotee.id == services.main_id)\
    .first()

def get_data():
    return [data.json(get) for get in data.query.all()]

@app.route('/getdata/<phonenumber>',methods=['GET'])
def getdata():
    return jsonify({'Devotee list': data.get_data()})
```

Comment: "it will raise an error" -> please [edit] your question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct

```
data = db.session.query(maindevotee, relatives, services)\
    .filter(maindevotee.phonenumber == 3251469870)\
    .join(relatives, maindevotee.id == relatives.main_id)\
    .join(services, maindevotee.id == services.main_id)\
    .first()
```

to

```
data = db.session.query(maindevotee, relatives, services)\
    .filter(
    (maindevotee.phonenumber == '3251469870')
    & (maindevotee.id == relatives.main_id)
    & (maindevotee.id == services.main_id)
    ).first()
```

for more clarifications, ask in the comments.

***Upon comment***

in

```
@app.route('/getdata/<phonenumber>',methods=['GET'])
def getdata():
    return jsonify({'Devotee list': data.get_data()})
```

`data` contains the query results, that do not include the function `get_data()`, therefore you face the mentioned error.

Try the following modification, I think this is the result form you may want:

```
@app.route('/getdata/<phonenumber>',methods=['GET'])
def getdata():
    return jsonify({**data.maindevotee.json(),**data.relatives.json(),**data.services.json()})
```

Good Luck

Comment: It will raise again same error. The error is     AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'get_data'

Comment: Firstly thank you for your reply .                                                                              return jsonify({'Devotee list': data.get_data()})   I think is there any correction in my code.